# how to change url of webview in MainActivity by clicking option menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have a WebView component in **`MainActivity`**, how can i change the url by clicking the option menu.

I have

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://designillusions.in/foodworld_app");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    .....
    }
```

I tried from **`NavigationDrawerFragment`** Class

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_my_account) {
        MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
        m.changeWebViewURL("http://designillusions.in/foodworld_app/my_account.php");
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

but not worked it closes the app...
Kindly help

Comment: You can't instantiate an Activity with `new`, and you wouldn't want to create a new instance anyway. Use `getActivity()` in Fragments. Also, whenever you have a crash, please provide the stacktrace from your logcat.

Comment: please, read more, learn more, do more by yourself! Just do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the onOptionsItemSelected inside MainActivity before calling super class.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_my_account)
        changeWebViewURL("http://designillusions.in/foodworld_app/my_account.php");

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```